# separation characters between picklists value - Set

Tags: apex, picklist, string, set

I have 6 multi picklists.

I pushed all the selected values into Set

For Example:

**Picklist A:**

Cherry

Apple

**Picklist B:**

Apricots

Avocado

**Picklist C:**

Banana

Blackberries

Blackcurrant

Assuming I selected all the values - Set will be :

Cherry;Apple, Apricots;Avocado, Banana;Blackberries;Blackcurrant

Which mean the Set is separated via **';'** between the values in the same picklist, but between picklists it will be separated with **','**

When I try now to use IN: in query, It kind of ruins me the query.

Any Idea how to replace everything to ';' or to ',' but not both?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Set<String>`, then there are no commas unless you concatenate the Set with a String to see a String version of the Set.

If each item in the Set is a multi-select picklist value, and you are doing SOQL queries there are special keywords such `includes` and `excludes` to help construct the appropriate queries. See [Querying Multi-Select Picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm) for more information.

Use this search - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=multi-select+picklist+query - to see examples on this forum too.